# How to sort the strings within an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, loops

I'm just trying to sort my strings alphabetically but while maintaining their position inside an array. For example, I have :

```
myArray = ["tree", "house", "show", "merit", "timer"]
```

and I'd like to perform an each loop on it in order to output :

```
myArray = ["eert", "ehosu", "hosw", and so on...]
```

I wanted to do something like this :

```
myArray.each do |x|
    x.chars.sort.join
end
```

For a single string that works but I guess "chars" doesn't work for multiple strings in an array. Or maybe it does and I'm not doing it right. Basically how would I modify it in order to get that output?

Comment: You are not sorting the strings, you are sorting the letters in a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need in order to make this work is to call [`map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) on `myArray`, instead of `each`.

The `map` method will change each element to the result of running the block on the original element.

```
myArray = ["tree", "house", "show", "merit", "timer"]
myArray.map do |x|
  x.chars.sort.join
end
# => ["eert", "ehosu", "hosw", "eimrt", "eimrt"]
```

Another thing to mention is that you are using camelCase for your variables, while the convention in Ruby is snake_case (`my_array` would be preferable).

Comment: Very true. Thanks a lot! I knew it wouldn't be too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting each element in the array. To do this, call the map function. I then broke down each element into multiple smaller array elements, and sorted that array. I transformed that array back into a sentence by using the join method.

```
myArray.map{|x|x.chars.sort{|x,y|x<=>y}.join}

=> ["eert", "ehosu", "hosw", "eimrt", "eimrt"]
```